# Showing a syntax error when I tried to do a project with treeview

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, treeview

Can anyone please tell me what's the issue with this code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from registration import DBConnect
class ListTicket():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db=DBConnect()
        self.root=tk.Tk()
        tv=ttk.Treeview(self.root)
        tv.pack()
        tv.heading("#0",text="ID")
        tv.column=("NAME")
        tv.column = ("GENDER")
        tv.column = ("COMMENTS")
        tv.heading("NAME",text="NAME")
        tv.heading("GENDER",text="GENDER")
        tv.heading("COMMENTS",text="COMMENTS")
        cursor =self.db.Show()
        for row in cursor:
            tv.insert("","end","#{}".format(row["ID"],text=row["ID"])) #1
            tv.set("#{}".format(row["ID"],column="NAME",value=row["name"]) #2
            tv.set("#{}".format(row["ID"],column="GENDER",value=row["gender"]) #3
            tv.set("#{}".format(row["ID"],column="COMMENTS",value=row["comment"]) #4
       self.root.mainloop()
```

I am getting a syntax error with line 2,3,4. I am taking values from a database.

Comment: Post the full error code please

Comment: NOTHING OTHER THAN SYNTAX ERROR.tv.set("#{}".format(row["ID"],column="GENDER",value=row["gender"])
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as your syntax error is concerned:

```
for row in cursor:
    tv.insert("","end","#{}".format(row["ID"],text=row["ID"])) #1
    tv.set("#{}".format(row["ID"],column="NAME",value=row["name"])) #2
    tv.set("#{}".format(row["ID"],column="GENDER",value=row["gender"])) #3
    tv.set("#{}".format(row["ID"],column="COMMENTS",value=row["comment"])) #4
```

You forgot to close the parenthesis at the end of every `tv.set()`.